# Get value in JetFormBuilder from Wordpress backend and previous form submission

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, jet-engine

I am using WordPress v6.2. I have a custom form made in JetFormBuilder, at the end of which I am sending a "Call Hook" Post Submit Action and calculating final variable in the backend, specifically in functions.php file.

```
add_action('jet-form-builder/custom-action/calculate-total', function ( $request ) {
.
.
.
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$total = 14500;
update_user_meta($user_id, $user_total_field, $total);
}
```

**No user will be logged in during this workflow.** I have to store the variable somewhere from the backend, where I can access it inside the JetFormBuilder hidden field or somewhere else in the JetFormBuilder. I was previously using user_meta for this. But since no user will be logged in, no user ID will be available.

[image]

total is the variable in the backend.

Also, I have some other variables, such as **otp** or **e-mail** which I have to store after the JetFormBuilder submission and access them in another JetForms form. I was previously storing them in user_meta which is now an nonviable option.

**Suggest some ways or custom code using which I can make this happen in JetFormBuilder and Wordpress backend.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Adding this as an answer as I'm currently unable to leave a comment under the first answer.*

As mentioned by @stephen-ostermiller, here are more details on using WP options. Here's a link to the codex for more info - https://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference

You can store data in the options table to be used across your WP site without it being tied to any specific page or post, making it the perfect solution for what you require. Example snippet on saving data as an option:

```
<?php add_option( 'var_total', '14500' ); ?>
```

If you are using ACF on your site, here's the guide on how to set up an options page using ACF - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/

Here's an example snippet of how to retrieve the data using ACF:

```
<?php $total = get_field('var_total', 'option'); ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can possibly use Option pages, as you can populate fields with it in the form.

Comment: Such a short answer is not high-quality.  Can you [edit] this to expand it?  It would be very helpful to see some example code.